# What is the best way to hold multiple 3D arrays in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, multidimensional-array

A program I am working on currently builds multiple differently sized 3D arrays (`50x50x200`, `30x30x100` for example).

I need to store these arrays in SQL, so I can pull them out again and display the arrays. I have come across [this thread](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-simplest-way-to-store-3-dimensional-arrays-in-a-SQL-database?share=1) where it describes the best way to store a 3D array. I will be using that data structure.

Another thing to mention would be that many of the same sized arrays will be created e.g. 10 `50x50x200`. My problem is how to go about storing these arrays. I have given this a lot of thought, and I have subsequently come to a few conclusions:

1. 1 table per array indexed with an ID `(x,y,z,ID)`
2. 1 table per array size e.g. `50x50` table, `30x30` table etc with a 4D array inside `(w,x,y,z,ID)`
3. 1 enormous table with a 5D array inside `(w,x,y,z,size,ID)` - size is whether the array is for example `30x30`

What would be the best way to go about storing these arrays?

---

***Edit:***

- All elements within an array will be retrieved at once;
- There is no need for updates within these arrays - once they are saved in SQL they will not change;
- After the original insertion, similar to updates, the arrays will not change;

Comment: The "best" way will depend on your use cases (and opinion-based). Will users retrieve all elements at once or single elements? What about inserts and updates?

Comment: @DanGuzman I realize I have not included enough information, apologies - I will edit with the correct information (in detail).

Comment: Since you have said you don't need to be able to change the arrays once stored, the critical remaining question seems to be "do you ever want to be able to apply predicates based on elements in the arrays from within SQL?" As pseudo-examples, `select * from MyArrays where count_of_x_elements = 5`, or `select * from MyArrays where x[0] = @someValue`, or `select * from MyArrays a1 join MyArrays a2 on a1.x[0] = a2.x[0]`, etc. If not, then just store them as blobs.

Comment: @allmhuran that completes depends on how the elements are stored, but I suspect I will have to be able to do something similar, yes.

Comment: @allmhuran Gordon's solution **does** account for order of elements `(ID,x,y,z,element value)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236781/discussion-between-joe-moore-and-allmhuran).

Comment: My bad, I had misread your requirements and thought you needed a "value" at the coordinates, not just the coordinates themselves.

Comment: My inclination based on your edits would be to store each array in a 2-column table, ID  int and JsonArray nvarchar(MAX). That would be efficient for both retrieval and storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way depends on how you are going to manipulate them.  If you simply need to store the array in SQL and do no manipulation, then you are storing an object.

You can store the entire object as a `varbinary` or `varchar()` using a single column.  To the database, they would look like a bunch of bits, which is fine for storing and retrieving.

If you were going to do any actions on the array, then you would want a more native solution.  That would probably involve two tables, an `arrays` table to define each array and an `arrayElements` table with one row per element in the array, so five columns:

- Array id.
- `x`, `y`, `z` coordinates.
- element value.

Comment: For example if I was to store 5 arrays with 100 elements each, the `arrays` table would define each array's `id`, and the `arrayElements` table would store the elements within each array (defined by `arrayID`)? Am I on the right track?

Comment: @JoeMoore . . . That would be the second approach.  But from what you describe, you can just treat the array as a BLOB and store it as a single value.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you.

Comment: @JoeMoore Hm, I think I retract my retraction. Gordon seems to have made the same misreading as I did... this schema would let you specify some scalar value that exists at some set of 3 dimensional coordinates (eg temperature in 3d space), but it wouldn't let you store a set of coordinates defining a volume of space per se. I *think* you actually want the latter, don't you? The 5 column schema here would work, but `element value` would have to be replaced with `element position`, and for non cubic volumes (jagged arrays) you could put nulls as appropriate (sparse columns might be good).

Comment: No, thats correct - I do want to store a scalar value at a set of 3 dimensional coords. I have prototyped this, and it works fine with no nulls. Thank you though.